# how to get User inputs in AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have scenario where I need user inputs in between AsyncTask, but doInBackground cannot display UI. 
Scenario:
On Button Click, There will be service call, based on the result of service call, I want to display Confirmation Dialog, If user clicks on Yes then there will be another service call and if user clicks on No then different service call. Facing issue in displaying ProgressDialog.

- Program Work flow:

  ```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

              bool result = Method1();
              if(result){
                              ShowConfirmation(new YesCallBackHelper() {Method2();}, new NoCallBackHelper() {Method3();});
              }
              else{
                              Method3();
              }

      }
  });


  private bool Method1()
  {
      return ServiceCall1();
  }

  private bool Method2()
  {
      return ServiceCall2();
  }

  private bool Method3()
  {
      return ServiceCall3();
  }
  ```

Comment: agree with @vickey's answer .for update UI from background thread ,you need to put your logic in runOnUiThread .

Answer (score 0):

```
onPreExecute() {
   // some code #1
}

doInBackground() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)

                }
            });
}

onPostExecute() {
   // some code #3
}
```

u can use runonuithread to manipulate UI from asynctask

Comment: can u pls explain where should i put AsynTask, on button click event or in all three service calls? it will be great if u can help for the same code from question

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot handle users interaction in `doInBackgroud()` method. However, you can do that `onPostExecute()` method
For example:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

OnPostExecute is invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter. Third parameter in AsyncTask is type of object you get as parameter in `onPostExecute()`

Documentation link : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Cheers!

Comment: there are couple of service calls which needs to be run in sequence and also in AsyncTask to display the ProgressDialog, can u pls help me with code .

Comment: run them in sequence from postExecute.

Comment: in that case i will have to write all codes in one method only, but Method1 is called from many places, it will be code redundancy....any other solution?

Comment: @Jignesh, familiar with SingleTon design pattern?https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Singleton_pattern 
Use a single Singleton class to handle your network call. You won't have to write redundant code. Just some methods/functions to parse your JSON responses. 

PS: if you have time, either shift to Retrofit or Volley. They are both faster (wayyyyy faster) than usual AsyncTask. 

Link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ & https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html